# How do I get the atoi function to work in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, command-line-arguments, arm64

I am trying to get this assembly program to print out an error message when the second argument on the command line is less than 0 or larger than 12. However when using it for some reason I always get a segfault when it is in that range.

```
define(i_r, w19)
define(argc_r, w20)
define(argv_r, x21)

fmt:     .string "%d "
err:     .string "usage: a5b mm dd\n"

        .balign 4
        .global main
main:   stp x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        mov x29, sp
        mov argc_r, w0          // Copy argc
        mov argv_r, x1          // Copy argv
        mov i_r, 1              // Start from the second argument
        cmp argc_r, 3           // Check if argc_r is 3
        b.ne error              // If argc_r != 3, go to error

        ldr x0, [argv_r, i_r, SXTW 3]   // Load the second argument string
        bl atoi                         // Convert string to integer
        cmp w0, 12                      // Check if the second argument is greater than 12
        bgt error                       // If greater than 12, go to error
        cmp w0, 0                       // Check if the second argument is less than 0
        blt error                       // If less than 0, go to error

        mov w1, w0                      // Move the converted integer to w1
        adrp x0, fmt                    // Load the format string
        add x0, x0, :lo12:fmt
        bl printf                       // Print the second argument

        add i_r, i_r, 1                 // Move to the next argument

top:    ldr x1, [argv_r, i_r, SXTW 3]   // Load the argument string
        bl atoi                         // Convert string to integer
        mov w1, w0                      // Move the converted integer to w1
        adrp x0, fmt                    // Load the format string
        add x0, x0, :lo12:fmt
        bl printf                       // Print the integer

        add i_r, i_r, 1                 // Move to the next argument
        cmp i_r, argc_r                 // Check if all arguments are processed
        b.lt top                        // If not, continue processing

end:
        ldp x29, x30, [sp], 16
        ret

error:
        adrp x0, err
        add x0, x0, :lo12:err
        bl printf
        b end
```

I've tried Moving the code for checking and printing the second argument (the month value) before the top label, but that still gives me the same result. I also tried changing the registers I used thinking it needed to be empty, but I still got the same result. I used gdb but it only seems that the bl atoi line is the problem, but I can't figure out specifically whats wrong with my logic. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: If your C compiler can output assembly code, use that as an example for the calling sequence.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Write a C program that calls atoi, then have it output assembly code.

Comment: The `bl atoi` is unlikely to be the problem, verify you are using the debugger correctly. Also, **which** one do you think is faulting? Anyway, the `top:    ldr x1, [argv_r, i_r, SXTW 3]` is loading `x1` instead of `x0` which is where `atoi` expects the argument so that definitely will not work. Furthermore your description says you only need to check the second argument so why are you trying to iterate all of them?

Comment: Would you kindly go back and read the answer I wrote for you last month at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77966377/634919, specifically the second bullet under "Calling convention violations"?

Comment: Moving the register to x0 still has the same result

Comment: @Jarvis What rcgldr is suggesting, my understanding, is that as you get closer to low level, high level approaches like when you call a function the compiler does many things for you, are not possible. Now you need to know how 'by convention' parameters and order of things are managed in the stack and other elements, imposed by a hardware architecture. Presumably, your C compiler is installed on your precise hardware so is already tuned to it. You can take advantage of the assembly code it can generate and try to mimic it.

Comment: I will point out that w20 and w21 are non-volatile registers.  You are using them without saving their values on the stack first.   You are probably messing up whatever function is calling you.